# imap_search not working with multiple criteria in php

Tags: php, imap

I am doing webmail project in php with imap. imap_search function is not working with multiple criteria. In single search criteria it is working fine. 
This is my code:

```
$boxes = imap_search($mbox, 'OR SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'" BODY "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
```

Comment: That looks more or less right (disregard what zzlalani says). Can you show the actual IMAP command that results? Have you tested with two servers? Btw, your code will break if the search term contains characters such as ", \, ë, or ±.

Comment: If i use "OR" keyword in imap_search it shows no result.For single criteria it is working fine. I have searched many reference. Not working. oh wat to do?

Comment: Try it with IMAP directly and see if it works. That way you'll know whether the issue is in the client code or server code. 'telnet imap.example.com 143', 'a login username password', 'b select inbox', 'c uid search or subject "arnt" body "arnt"'. If that doesn't work it's a server issue, if it works you have to find out what your code generates and why it doesn't generate the right command. Have fun.

Comment: Try outputting what you are passing in the OR clause to see if you have any variables that are incorrectly set. Otherwise do as @arnt suggests and manually interact with the IMAP server to troubleshoot the issue. You can use telnet, or something like my IMAPTalk client if you're on Windows.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestions. I have written the code with some basic condition. Now it is working fine. Here is my code.                                           //for multiple search criteria starts here for concatenate
  $boxes = imap_search($mbox, 'FROM "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
  //check if first search have mails or not
  if($boxes){
   if(imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID))
       $boxes =$boxes+imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
  } else {
   $boxes = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
  }

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PHP 5.5.12 on Windows and I confirm the "OR" operator doesn't work with the function Imap_search(). You need to make multiple queries to the server in order to get the results you want.

It might also be worth mentionning using the keywords "BODY" or "TEXT" to search the body of emails will also match content located in the headers (eg. FROM, TO, SUBJECT) using Imap_search().

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'TO "'.$email.'" SUBJECT "'.$search_text.'"',E_UID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you for your suggestions. I have written the code with some basic condition. Now it is working fine. Here is my code.

```
//for multiple search criteria starts here for concatenate 
$boxes = imap_search($mbox, 'FROM "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);

//check if first search have mails or not 
if( $boxes )
{ 
    if( imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID) ) 
    {
        $boxes = $boxes + imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $boxes = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be

```
$SUBJECT = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
$BODY = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);

$boxes = array_merge($SUBJECT, $BODY);
```

Comment: you want `OR` query or `AND` query?

Comment: OR only... If user search with any single keyword in front end , we will check in all sections in mail message like(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,BODY) then show him with filter result.

Comment: @zzlalani First one is not working. Second one is showing the result 2 times and looking slow one.

Comment: As @arnt already mentioned, IMAP uses prefix notation, so it won't work as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use `array_merge` or `array_intersect` need to `$SUBJECT` and `$BODY` to temporary variables

```php
$SUBJECT = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);
$BODY = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$search_keyword.'"', SE_UID);

$I = $SUBJECT;
$J = $BODY;

$boxes = array_merge($I,$J);
```